# Icon is identical to History

Tags: bug, icon

Our Icon is an "H" inside an SE bubble, this is identical to the icon of the already existing History.SE.

The Icon for the Health site should be changed to avoid confusion.

Comment: I'm guessing by the lack of status declined when Rob edited it that this may change...?

Answer (score 14):

Nice catch, didn't even notice. Obviously we will have to change our logo because we are the newer site. I have a few ideas for a new logo. We could just do "HE", but that is a little boring. I was also thinking we could possibly do a red cross, but that would conflict with Christianity a little. I think that a heart might be good. I don't think this would conflict with any other sites and it would probably look good too.

**What I now recommend, is to do a [heartbeat](http://www.iconexperience.com/_img/i_collection_png/512x512/plain/heartbeat.png) icon. Some people might confuse the heart for romance, but the heartbeat icon is obviously related to health. (Idea from Zach Saucier in the comments)**

I've decided to try to design the heartbeat logo, so here it is. Let me know what you guys think.

[image: Bigger Heartbeat Icon]

More accurate heartbeat made by @Tim, red and white versions (the small size gets cutoff)

[image: More accurate heartbeat]

[image]

If you would like to improve it, here is an SVG link: https://openclipart.org/download/216852/heartbeato.svg

Comment: I'd prefer HE as a heart implies more romance than it does health to me. Or perhaps a [heart beat](http://www.iconexperience.com/_img/i_collection_png/512x512/plain/heartbeat.png) icon

Comment: @ZachSaucier that depends on the kind of heart logo. :-)

Comment: I don't think they will go for icon until graduation.

Comment: How about "Rx"? :-)

Comment: @AnkitSharma aviation.se, lego.se, and poker.se all are beta site with icons in the logo.

Comment: @StrongBad never visited any of them, my bad.

Comment: @ZachSaucier Just edited in the possiblity of a heartbeat icon

Comment: @StrongBad anime.se and chess.se also.

Comment: I hope you mean [this kind of heart](https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1918&bih=1111&q=heart&oq=heart&gs_l=img.3..0l10.769.1265.0.1382.5.4.0.1.1.0.100.363.3j1.4.0.msedr...0...1ac.1.64.img..0.5.365.5dkswPQZMKk#tbm=isch&q=human+heart+clipart&revid=1212764113&imgdii=_&imgrc=ukLziBlO0dOAVM%253A%3Bsp_Z-0mgrmyNqM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fimages.clipartpanda.com%252Fhuman-heart-clip-art-human-heart-4232178.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fgalleryhip.com%252Fclip-art-human-heart.html%3B971%3B1300).

Comment: @Jez Drug prescriptions? o.O

Comment: Heart icon? [Shameless promotion from my post on meta.LH](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mzN7y.png) (but without wrench, I'm just too lazy to edit it :P). But I agree with Zach's comment that it might be assumed as relationship/romance. I think heartbeat would be better :)

Comment: I'd say remove the graph. At least from the favicon, or else it looks like a broken heart...

Comment: @Shimmy Re-did, should look better now. What do you think?

Comment: @michaelpri as before, it's very nice, as the app icon. for favicon i still prefer the whole heart. You know what let's see some examples...

Comment: @Shimmy The heart without any lines?

Comment: @michaelpri oops. I wanted to edit your post and copy the icon in a [smaller size](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253405/75500), but the edit button is disabled

Comment: @michaelpri yep. no lines - my taste - keep it simple remove the graph it just complicates things. at least for the favicon.

Comment: @Shimmy Some people think that a plain heart is more related to romance than health

Comment: How about one of the hospital signs? See [this](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/a/59/115). Anyway I keep my upvote on your suggestion cuz I think it's neat.

Comment: Now it's a broken heart. Still romance, but sadder. :'(

Comment: Just as an aside, if that is an ECG tracing, that person has some serious trouble. :p

Comment: @Tim Nice, that's so much better than mine. I converted it to .png, but it won't let me upload. If you can figure it out, please do edit it

Comment: Love the heart with the EKG tracing in it. Classy. A figurative broken heart usually breaks vertically, not horizontally.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Well no, michaelpri made it, I made it svg and with a real (ish) EGC :P I would never have had that idea! And it turns out it was Zach Saucier's idea http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/10/59#comment6_13

Comment: Whoever contributed, I love it!

Comment: @anongoodnurse I'm thinking about opening a post for people to formally vote on their favorite logo and ideas

Comment: @michaelpri I'm making svg logos for each of the suggestions here. want all the links?

Comment: SVGs: https://openclipart.org/download/216852/heartbeato.svg https://openclipart.org/download/216861/heartbeatw.svg https://openclipart.org/download/216865/ecgl.svg https://openclipart.org/download/216869/snakelogo.svg https://openclipart.org/download/216872/rx.svg https://openclipart.org/download/216874/Hp.svg

Comment: PNGs (white background so imgur resizing looks okay): http://i.stack.imgur.com/rosg6.png http://i.stack.imgur.com/Lu5EB.png http://i.stack.imgur.com/SAGRX.png http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSt3z.png http://i.stack.imgur.com/7UzGT.png http://i.stack.imgur.com/yvO8G.png

Comment: PNGs (no background): http://i.stack.imgur.com/cf7z0.png http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ol22U.png http://i.stack.imgur.com/subBQ.png http://i.stack.imgur.com/Pi7MR.png http://i.stack.imgur.com/fUMXV.png http://i.stack.imgur.com/cVUJj.png

Comment: @michaelpri All of them: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252889 Do you want to start the voting question or shall I?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22608/discussion-between-tim-and-michaelpri).

Comment: @ZachSaucier @FaheemMitha @AnkitSharma @Jez @StrongBad @michaelpri @Scimonster @bjb568 @JasonC @AndrewT. @Shimmy @JohnP @Tim @anongoodnurse We have opened a question (http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/130/voting-for-a-new-icon) for you to vote on which idea for the logo you like best. Please bear in mind that SE won't necessarily chose the highest voted one, if any (I don't know how they create the logos). However, please vote for your favorite(s) so we have some idea.`

Comment: I vote hands down for the cross. Either a red one but box it, to distinguish from christianity, or in blue/light-blue [see](http://i.imgur.com/JJDI0oC.jpg?1).

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest a icon version of a nice ECG of a heart in normal sinus rhythm.

[image]

Good sinus rhythm being usually seen a good health symptom.

[Source of image](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9e/SinusRhythmLabels.svg/1024px-SinusRhythmLabels.svg.png) "SinusRhythmLabels" by Created by Anthony Atkielski. Licensed under Public Domain via Wikimedia Commons

Comment: The WPW delta wave is missing ;-)

Comment: Beta sites don't usually get custom logos.

Comment: @Scimonster   StrongBad already stated that "aviation.se, lego.se, and poker.se all are beta site with icons in the logo."

Comment: A simple icon doesn't mean an image. All of those are actually just Unicode symbols.

Comment: @Sci All of the icons are images.

Comment: @jasonc I mean, the stuff in the bubble is just a Unicode symbol. I'm pretty sure they generate them using something.

Comment: https://openclipart.org/download/216865/ecgl.svg is an SVG format ECG and I have the PNG if you want to insert it into the answer.

Comment: @UweKeim @M'vy We have opened a question (http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/130/voting-for-a-new-icon) for you to vote on which idea for the logo you like best. Please bear in mind that SE won't necessarily chose the highest voted one, if any (I don't know how they create the logos). However, please vote for your favorite(s) so we have some idea.`

Answer (score 2):

How about one of the hospital sign.

[image][image]

The H sign could work if it's not as light-blue as the history, and that it's lacking the talk balloon, and having it look more like a hospital sign. Plus it's obviously referring to Health as well.
Anyway personally I like the plus sign more.
Maybe just make a SE icon template (with balloon that wraps the plus), to make it SE-specific.
I think the dark-blue color emphasizes it's something else.

And I'm sharing you here with [Tim's suggestion](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/icon-is-identical-to-history/59#comment268_59) as well (ignore the black background):

[image]

Again the idea could be nice but the plus sign will barely be recognizable as a favicon. Perhaps changing increasing the plus sign could work.
IMHO the final icon should have one main idea leveraged by all the the awesome ideas suggested in this thread.

Comment: Not sure if they will change the layout for ungraduated sites. I did mention the red cross in my answer, but it may conflict with the Christianity icon

Comment: Are they going to allow red color in icon else this will be plain plus sign.

Comment: I removed the red cross, because as michaelpri commented, he has mentioned that before [here](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/a/13/115). I actually still keep the post for the reference but I'm still with either heartbeat or cross. I doubt like the light-blue color tho, I think it should be either dark blue as in [StrongBad's suggestion](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/a/32/115) (See [my comment](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/10/icon-is-identical-to-history/59#comment83_32) there), or red.

Comment: https://openclipart.org/download/216874/Hp.svg is an SVG format H+ and I have the PNG if you want to insert it into the answer.

Comment: @Tim, I didn't have patience to remove the black background yet. You know you could update my answer yourself.

Comment: @Shimmy I don't have the rep yet (nearly). The ones with white background are all http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/130/voting-for-a-new-icon here for voting on.

Answer (score 1):

I propose that the icon should use the [Rod of Asclepius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rod_of_Asclepius) which is the serpent-entwined rod in the middle of the Star of Life:

[image]

Comment: To me, this looks way too detailed to be recognizable in a 16x16 pixel icon.

Comment: I do like this sign a lot, it's just the snake that should be omitted.

Comment: I dunno, this reminds me of Blue Cross Blue Shield, even though its not the same shape.

Comment: I think this leans too much towards medical/clinical, as this is the basis of almost every EMS logo I know.

Comment: https://openclipart.org/download/216869/snakelogo.svg is an SVG format Snake and I have the PNG if you want to insert it into the answer.

Comment: @Tim, Look at [Uwe's comment](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/10/icon-is-identical-to-history/59#comment22_32). I think the OP's solution looks better and more identifiable as a health-related forum. I'd say the snake should be totally removed.

Comment: @shimmy, the "snake" is the Rod of Asclepius and I would argue is what makes this health related, see the original link to Wikipedia. The Star of Life is just one logo that uses the Rod.  I am not a graphic designer and have no idea if it could work as a 16x16 pixel icon, but I am not sure that is a requirement.

Answer (score -4):

Another option that scales down well is **Rx**, although this may be too narrowly associated with drugs.

Comment: "May be" is an understatement.

Comment: Correct symbol (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medical_prescription)): ℞, though honestly I just knew for the first time that this is a symbol of medical prescription. Without a hint from [Jason's comment](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/10/icon-is-identical-to-history#comment53_13), I wouldn't even know the relationship between "Health" and "Rx" (I never see this symbol in my life until now)

Comment: Fair enough. I have an association in my mind with Rx and health care, but that's probably just me.

Comment: I had to Look it up - as did @AndrewT. Maybe this is an American / Non-American thing?

Comment: https://openclipart.org/download/216872/rx.svg is an SVG format Rx Logo and I have the PNG if you want to insert it into the answer.

Comment: @NateBarbettini We have opened a question (http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/130/voting-for-a-new-icon) for you to vote on which idea for the logo you like best. Please bear in mind that SE won't nececarialy chose the highest voted one, if any (I don't know how they create the logos). However, please vote for your favorite(s) so we have some idea.`