# Are questions about Medical History on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Though [this question](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/icon-is-identical-to-history) is completely unrelated, it got me thinking. Should we allow questions about Medical History to be asked here? I was thinking that one of these questions could be like

> When was {disease} first identified?

or

> What led to the myth that {medical myth} is true?

I do think that these types of questions would be interesting, but would they be a good fit here?

Answer (score 12):

I would think they would be on topic as they can easily relate to current medical issues. There might be some controversy over some topics as some are considered myth by some people and considered fact by others. An example of this is the debate over vaccination and you will find people on both sides of that posting on this site.

The main problem will be keeping them from becoming primarily opinion based rather then fact based.

Answer (score 6):

The site claims to be for "health-related questions". History is not really health related to me. It might be a sub-topic of a discussion, if someone wants indication about difference between current and old medications for example, but purely historical question seems off-topic to me.

Furthermore:

> When was {disease} first identified?

Is encyclopaedia question, so definitely not worth here.

> What led to the myth that {medical myth} is true?

Is probably primarily opinion based.