# Voting for a new icon

Tags: discussion, icon

Once Health.SE was started we quickly realized that [we have the same logo as History.SE](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/icon-is-identical-to-history/). In the answers of that post, many great ideas were brought up. [@Tim](https://health.stackexchange.com/users/163/tim) made a few designs for the great ideas that people came up with. For this post, you can vote for your favorite designs. If you have another design or idea that you'v come up with, feel free to post it.

We will try to get the design with the most votes to be our icon.

Comment: SE will decide on the temporary icon for the site, I strongly doubt any voting here would be useful. They generally take input from the community for the final design, but the beta icon is just a placeholder. Collecting ideas does no harm, but I don't see any value in a formal voting.

Comment: @MadScientist It just seemed like there were many great ideas, so I wanted the community to decide what they liked best instead of having a few people control it

Comment: I agree with @MadScientist: it seems a bit premature.  After all, some sites stay in beta for a long time, the longest current one being [Board and Card Games at over 4 years](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5220/board-and-card-games).

Comment: @Garrett Some sites have requested and gotten custom logos: ie: [Aviation.SE](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/178/new-icon-for-aviation)

Comment: @Garrett We are hoping we will get this if we go public :)

Comment: Is this a question about the Beta-site favicon (which traditionally feature a blue speech-bubble), or a question about the icon after graduation? For a beta icon, surely it only needs to differentiate from History (so HE would do fine); for post-graduation, you get a custom-designed favicon based on the new site design. This Meta question appears to jump the gun.

Comment: so, should we pick one now?

Answer (score 17):

Rod of Asclepius

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

[SVG Link if you would like to edit](https://openclipart.org/download/216869/snakelogo.svg)

Comment: Can we add the favicon size to each of these answers? I feel like this has too much detail for a small size

Comment: @Zach am right now :)

Comment: @michaelpri I use https://inkscape.org/en/ none look great at 16px tbh :/

Comment: @michaelpri Yeah, that may be what it chosen :/ I like the white heart one the most but it is unclear at favicon size so I'm not sure :(

Comment: @Tim I want the white heart too, but I agree, it get's blurry when it's too small

Comment: @michaelpri see the pixel perfect one I made

Comment: This one looks bit religious to me.

Comment: Maybe for the small icons, try chopping off the bottom half and just having the top half with the head.  That way you can fit more of its detail in.

Comment: Too much shape in my opinion. Even in the bigger ones.

Answer (score 14):

White heart with ECG tracing (V1 and V2.0, with more realistic trace, V2.1 curved trace):

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

[SVG Link if you would like to edit](https://openclipart.org/download/216861/heartbeatw.svg)

Comment: At favicon size the ECG trace is not visible. Why not just the heart?

Comment: @Tim Arqade also used to have a heart!

Comment: @Tim A pixel-perfect icon of that size could work, but it would take more time than I've got to make one.

Comment: @Tim An icon drawn in pixels rather than with vectors. It allows far greater control and provides a much higher quality image at small sizes. [This article on pixel fitting](http://dcurt.is/pixel-fitting) should explain what I mean.

Comment: Just throwing this out there (@Tim): the little downward blip before the p wave doesn’t reflect any physiologic scenario I’m aware of. *Not that anyone would be able to see it*...but if anyone does care to blow it up to look, that piece is nonsensical. (P and t waves are also rounded, not acute like that. The QRS looks great!)

Comment: @Tim Interesting, I’m not sure what that blip is intended to be in that image.  [This](http://www.practicalclinicalskills.com/ekg-reference-guide-details.aspx?lessonID=1) is the sort of thing I’m accustomed to. (I know you don’t want the red grid, but just so you can see what the waveforms are supposed to look like.)

Comment: @Susan, Yeah I just checked with my mother (I showed a google search and she pointed out that one!)... I will edit now, 1 minute :)

Comment: @Susan 48 minutes later... :P what do you think? I prefered it straight to curved, but I removed the pointless blip.

Comment: @Tim You're fast! Much better, thanks.

Comment: @michaelpri yeah, they came out well! They recognisable as well... :)

Comment: Hope so *fingers crossed*!

Comment: yeah, if we get out of private beta

Comment: V2.1 looks somehow weird to me. I like V1 and V2.0

Comment: I just plain don't like this icon.  It looks like "the broken hearts society" or something.

Comment: This is my favorite at full-size, but it's really difficult to discern at favicon size without knowing what it is already.

Comment: Please take a look at this: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/heartbeat/

Answer (score 8):

Plain ECG tracing (V1 + V2)

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

[SVG Link if you would like to edit](https://openclipart.org/download/216865/ecgl.svg)

Comment: I like this one the best; the only issue I see is whether it would scale down to favicon size well.

Comment: As it could be interpreted as data, I vote against this idea

Comment: It does look like a CPU trace or something

Comment: @NateBarbettini it come out brilliantly, but none do really. See the edit.

Comment: *it doesn't come out

Answer (score 8):

I'm not too much of graphic designer, **so I beg you** not to measure the pixels in my image and be able to imagine it in various **color**s (read on).

Anyway, I'd still vote for the cross [suggested by @michaelpri](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13/115).

The cross should be either red (maybe boxed - as in first-aid box - to distinguish from christianity), dark blue, or light blue, or one of the above in a white background (see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdaKO.jpg)).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Or just white:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here's an image with a white cross and a red background.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here's one with a red cross and white background with a black around the outside.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Which gives a hint of (see more [here](http://bit.ly/1st-aid-kit)):

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Maybe the red should be a bit lighter.

Comment: This is the only one that can really be seen at favicon size.

Comment: @Eric. 1) Let's not forget that this was originally proposed by [@michaelpri](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/10/icon-is-identical-to-history/13#13). 2) I've updated my post.

Comment: White cross on red makes me think of Switzerland, not of health.

Answer (score -1):

"He" for Health

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

[SVG Link if you want to edit](https://openclipart.org/download/216877/he.svg)

Comment: Thanks for doing all this. I'm voting on my favorites. This one made me laugh, though. It looks like laughing, and it reminds me of a leaking helium balloon. Who knew this could be so evocative? Again, thanks!

Comment: @Anon pleasure :) I enjoy making these!

Comment: First we have hydrogen ions (H+), now helium. :)

Comment: @NateBarbettini :p leave my drawings alone ;)

Comment: In all seriousness, thanks for putting together the visuals.

Comment: He he he he he.

Comment: @Nate pleasure :p I love doing these things - someone actually *needs* my skills for once!

Answer (score -3):

"Li" for Life

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

[SVG Link if you want to edit](https://openclipart.org/download/216877/he.svg)

Comment: @michaelpri, health and life are intimately related.  Besides I was just joking, H, He, Li ...

Comment: @NinjaDoc Haha :) Who's going to propose "Be" now? ^^

Comment: Li for Lithium, an anti-depressant drug. THIS SITE IS A SHIM FOR BIG PHARMA!!! ;-)

Comment: Now I want to add "Ox" as in oxygen...