# Who should our Moderators Pro Tempore be?

Tags: discussion, moderation

This community needs to start contributing some names they would like to act as provisional Moderators. Please read this: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)**.

Here are some basic guidelines:

- Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity ([see this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150/elect-our-provisional-moderators) for reference).
- The nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer (not commenting), adding that they accept the nomination. Optionally they can write something about themselves. Use the `---` to separate it from the nomination.
- Self nominations are okay, and even encouraged. Most sites have not had sufficient time for many users to stand out. Self nomination is simply a way to say, “I’m interested. Let my record speak for itself.” Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts / social network referrals about the site, etc.

Here is what we are looking for in a Moderator...

We are seeing out members who are deeply engaged in the community’s development; members who:

- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in A Theory of Moderation.

Bonus points for:

- Members with participation in both meta and the parent site (i.e. interest in both community building and expertise in the field).
- Area 51 participation, social network referrals, or blogging about the site.
- Members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.

Please try to use a format similar to the following when posting a nomination under this question:

> ## [Name](https://health.stackexchange.com/users/-1/)
>
> <sup>(liked to profile)</sup>
>
> ### [Meta](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/)
>
> <sup>(linked to meta profile)</sup>
>
> <sup>Details about the nominee</sup>
>
> They are active on both the main and meta sites. They were involved in the Scope creation and took lead in closing the Off Topic questions.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>Edited in by nominee</sup>
>
> I accept / decline this nomination
>
> I am Name / Age / Fun Fact <sup>1</sup> and I live in Location, so will be active on the site from Xpm - Ypm HTZ<sup>2</sup> (Δpm - Ωpm UTC).
>
> <sup>1 Optional
>
>   2 Home Time Zone, Optional but nice to know</sup>

Your answer should be Community post Wiki so the nominee can edit it. Even if you are self nominating, CW is nice for consistency.

Comment: Any reason for down voting the *question*? Do you disagree that we need moderators?

Comment: I don't understand why this has -2. If you downvoted, please explain why so we can improve.

Answer (score 21):

## [Susan](https://health.stackexchange.com/users/165/susan)

### [Meta](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/users/165/susan)

[http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/4052760.png?theme=dark](http://stackexchange.com/users/4052760)

Always calm, professional, knowledgeable, with a non-biased state of mind, Susan does help us a lot. Being able to write such answers<sup>[1](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/120/why-do-doctors-prescribe-steroid-tablets-even-though-they-know-the-side-effects/307#307),[2](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/11/are-calcium-supplements-harmful-even-if-you-stay-short-of-the-maximum-dose/424#424)</sup> and comments<sup>[3](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/11/are-calcium-supplements-harmful-even-if-you-stay-short-of-the-maximum-dose/424#comment722_424)</sup> leads me to think she would do a great moderator.

Looks like she is also a medical professional or biologist (same here, please correct me if I'm wrong).

Please accept, Susan :)

---

I accept this nomination. If asked, it would be my pleasure to serve as a moderator here.

I live in UTC -5/-4, but if my SE activity patterns were reviewed I suspect you would find no circadian pattern whatsoever. I reserve the right to be here at any time of day or night.  :-)

Comment: Susan is helpful and knowledgeable - perfect traits for a moderator.

Comment: Agreed. Susan is exactly the type of contributor I'd hope Health.SE would attract.

Comment: My experience suggests Susan would be an excellent pick as moderator for this site. Besides being a knowledgeable medical professional, she has high standards for post quality that will be critical for this site to succeed and is level-headed and able to step back to analyze 'situations' rather than get caught up in them. Our interaction has mostly been on [hermeneutics.se] where she was added to the pro-tem mod team after somebody resigned. She's learned the ropes there well, has earned the community's respect, and has taken initiative that has significantly improved the site for everyone.

Answer (score 9):

## [Fomite](https://health.stackexchange.com/users/206/fomite)

### [Meta](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/users/206/fomite)

[http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/465049.png?theme=dark](http://stackexchange.com/users/465049)

Although he has only been around for about a week, Fomite has already contributed many informative answers reflecting obvious expertise in the area. He has also been active on meta, pointing out potential difficulties with the site and making insightful observations about how we should approach them. He has an extensive history of valuable posts on other SE sites including Academia, Cross Validated, and Biology, indicating a solid understanding of the SE platform and how our communities work.

---

**I am happy to accept this nomination**

I started off a little late in the private beta (this site launching corresponded rather perfectly with some travel), but I've been trying to contribute decent quality answers where I can, and thinking about how the community can be structured to draw both casual users and experts.

I'm technically on Eastern Standard Time, but my schedule is pretty wide ranging - I'm up at all hours of the night, and tend to have StackExchange sites sitting in the background while I work, checking in occasionally.

Answer (score 8):

## [anongoodnurse](https://health.stackexchange.com/users/169/anongoodnurse)

### [Meta](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/users/169/anongoodnurse)

[http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/3674367.png?theme=dark](http://stackexchange.com/users/3674367)

Anongoodnurse (aka medica) has been extremely helpful in advancing this site. In my encounters with her, she has been very friendly and polite and she has also helped me improve the quality of my questions and answers.

She is also a Parenting.SE moderator, so she is familiar with moderating.

I believe that she is also a medical professional (correct me if I'm wrong), which I think is something we need in a mod for this site.

---

**Thank you for the nomination; I'm sorry to decline.**

I appreciate the consideration and support I've received, especially for being so new. I believe the other nominees have better demonstrated their commitment to the site and have a fuller appreciation of its vision.

I will be happy to continue to contribute on the site and here in meta, and look forward to its success!

Comment: +1 she has been pleasant, helpful and kind!

Comment: She has shown a volatile and at times hostile attitude to me.  I would recommend against her being a moderator.

Comment: @Jez Could you link to that so we can see the specifics? I wonder if there was a misunderstanding. My experience has been very different, more like Tim’s.

Comment: @Jez Same here. Like Susan and Tim said.

Comment: @Jez it would be nice to see some evidence for this claim?

Comment: Currently you have +5 -1 (4). Someone has gone through and downvoted *everyone*.

Comment: OK then.  http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19408270#19408270 - "But don't ask me anything again."  Read the transcript backlog for context.  Extremely hostile, unpleasant reaction to something I'd said that was merely a joke.  I find her personality to be inappropriate for being a mod.

Comment: @jez not every person or moderator will get along with everyone that is life. Even the most likable people have annoyed someone at some point whether by accident or not but this is the by product to being human and having emotions--everyone at some time will make a bad call. You don't judge people on isolated incidents. If that was the case, no one would every be president, mayor, a leader, a policemen, military, etc.

Comment: It's a little late now, but I wanted to say Jez is right. I have a history with him. For anyone interested in the background to @Jez's comment, please see [reply in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21048748#21048748). Apologies for the drama.

Comment: My experience has been that of Tim's and Susan's. Not sure why you have so many downvotes.

Comment: I don't get it either about those downvotes. We need more medical professionals and it's probably not the best way to encourage them to contribute.

Comment: To all the people wondering about downvotes, it could simply be that anongoodnurse already declined.

Comment: @Sterno Why downvoting a declined nomination?

Comment: I didn't, but why not? No sense having someone who doesn't have the interest bubble to the top of the nominations.

Comment: @Sterno People can change their mind.

Comment: People can change their votes, too.

Comment: These down-votes have their own [reasons](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/325). Hopefully we'll get some more. This site is broadly [sick](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/332/114) since appointment of the wrong pro-temp mods (for over half an year) and in my opinion something needs to be [change](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/325/114) asap.

Answer (score 8):

## [JohnP](https://health.stackexchange.com/users/64/JohnP)

### [Meta](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/users/64/JohnP)

[http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1511762.png?theme=dark](http://stackexchange.com/users/1511762)

I have been active every day since the private beta launch with some activity pre launch in Area 51. I have participated in several private betas that have made it to public beta status (Woodworking, Beer among others) and I am active on several other public beta sites as well. I believe I have a good base of both knowledge and activity on the regular and the meta sites. While I have not been a SE moderator yet, I have served as a moderator on several different forums in the past few years.

I would be honored to be one of the pro-tem moderators, and I believe that I could be a contributing member of a good moderation team.

Edited: I have been asked for history. My first degree is in exercise kinesiology (Study of human movement), which includes several classes on maturation milestones and aging differences, injury treatment and lifestyle/nutrition management. I worked as an ambulance medic for 2 years and in an Air Force ER for 3 years active and 4 years reserve as a primary medic and Air Transportable Hospital response member. I have continued over the years to be active in coaching in several sports, and have continued refresher education in various health subjects.

I am available generally from 9am EST until 12am EST, as I work in an area where I am on the computer most of the day.

Comment: John is a first-aid man. He can ressucite the whole site's community anytime ;)

Comment: For those that are downvoting, if you would leave your concerns I believe I can address them. I do realize I can be a bit acerbic in my tone.

Comment: @JohnP Well someone has gone through and downvoted *everyone*.

Comment: I edited to corrected a technicality in your nomination as neither site you mention has actually graduated to "full status". Beer has been it public beta for a while and appears to be struggling with very low volume. Woodworking is only recently in public beta and you haven't even rounded out you Area51 commitment to it yet. I'm not saying anything much about your nomination: you might make a great moderator and how the process works is something you can learn as you go along but experience with bringing SE sites through graduation doesn't seem to be in your experience set just yet.

Comment: @Caleb - Thanks for the clarification. :)

Answer (score 7):

## [Shlublu](https://health.stackexchange.com/users/102/shlublu)

### [Meta](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/users/102/shlublu)

[http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/447369.png?theme=dark](http://stackexchange.com/users/447369/shlublu)

I haven't had much interaction with Shlublu, but he been a helpful, active member on this site, both on beta and meta, where he has posted many high quality answers. Shlublu is also a Certified First Responder in France, so has experience that could really benefit this site.

---

### I'm sorry I have to decline this nomination :/

I appreciate that very much, both this nomination and the support it receives! 
I don't think I would be a good moderator though, as I cannot commit to any kind of availability. Sometimes I'm here and available for a week, sometimes I'm away without notice for a while... this is not steady/constant enough for a mod.

I'll be happy to keep contributing! As much as I'll be able to, my scope being a bit narrow :)

---

Answer (score 6):

## [michaelpri](https://health.stackexchange.com/users/26/michaelpri)

### [Meta](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/users/26/michaelpri)

[http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/4642421.png?theme=dark](http://stackexchange.com/users/4642421)

I think michaelpri would also make a good moderator. He has experience, as he is a moderator pro-tem on lifehacks, and has been active (In fact, is the leading reputation person on the site) in asking and answering/refining questions, meta and in chat. He has been a primary driver of the private beta since launch.

---

### I gladly accept this nomination

I have been very interested in this site from its first day in beta. I don't have any background in health, but I come from a family of nurses, so it has always been a topic in my household. I am currently a [Moderator Pro Tempore on Lifehacks.SE](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), so I am familiar with moderating on SE. Lifehacks isn't the most busy site, so I would still have time to be a moderator here. I am young (14), but this has never been a problem during my SE experience. I live near Philadelphia, Pennsylvania, USA, so I go by Eastern Standard Time.

Activity on Health*:

- Not on: 4:00 UTC - 11:00 UTC/12:00 a.m. EST - 7:00 a.m. EST
- On sporadically: 12:00 UTC - 8:00 UTC/8:00 a.m. EST - 4:00 p.m. EST
- Have SE on an open tab: 8:00 UTC - 4:00 UTC/4:00 p.m. EST - 12:00 a.m. EST

---

<sup>*These times may vary</sup>

Comment: I can attest to his diligent moderation of Lifehacks. +1

Comment: Happy to vote for you. Your answer quality sets the standard for everyone else on the site.

Comment: Question for Michael: How do you think moderating this site will be different from moderating Lifehacks, if at all?

Comment: @michaelpri You say the people here should be experts, yet you're one of the highest reputation users and you're only 14. How do you explain that?

Comment: Sorry, @michaelpri. I should have been clearer. You seem pretty mature and I think you're doing a fine job moderating on Lifehacks. I don't have a problem with you as a moderator. What concerned me was your statement that this seems to be a place for experts. I think anyone in the medical field would take issue with the idea that you poking around on the internet for 2 weeks make you "almost an expert" on health matters. But this is not a criticism of you in particular. Right now I don't see anything here that forces users to be more "expert" than Lifehacks.

Comment: @Sterno Sorry, I also need to be a bit clearer. "Expert" probably wasnt the right wording for explaining me. I more of an enthusiast now. On Lifehacks, I feel that there is more of a laid back attitude for the users, which isn't a bad thing. Almost everyone has a life hack or two that they could share. From what I can tell, the user base here is different.

Comment: @Sterno  There is more of a professional feel, at least to me. To have a good answer here, you have to put in more work than you would on LH. Overall, what I'm trying to say is that on LH, anyone can be an enthusiast. Here, I think there will be a more exclusive group of top posters, people who are interested and willing to do research. Sorry for some of my wording and not being clear, I'm in school on my mobile.

Comment: @TomMedley It would be different moderating here than Lifehacks, but the same can probably be said for almost all sites. I think the users here are different than from Lifehacks, so that will obviously be different. I also think that I will have to moderate answers on here more than on LH because on LH, it's hard for there to be a wrong answer, but on here, bad information could come up a lot. (PS: This is my new answer, as my other one caused a little confusion.)

Comment: @michaelpri It's not a moderator's job to do anything to incorrect answers except perhaps downvote them, just as any normal user would do, is it? What, specifically, do you think actions a moderator needs to take here with regards to answers?

Comment: @Sterno I think that as a mod, your word will be taken more seriously if you disagree with someone's answer, so even though you don't have to take an actual moderator action, you do have more responsibility with bad information. Also [this meta post](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/155/two-roads-diverged-in-a-yellow-wood) sometimes there are answers that don't actually answer the question. Mods will also have to deal with those types of answers.

Comment: @michaelpri - Why would "your word" be stronger if you disagree with an answer? Whether or not you agree with an answer should make a difference. Unless the answer violates SE protocol, your function as a moderator should be the same as everyone else, downvote.

Comment: That should have been "Should not make a difference".

Comment: @JohnP What I was trying to say is that you have to be more careful when you disagree with an answer. If you comment after you downvote, people are more likely to downvote also if you have a diamond next to your name. Of course, this is only in my experience on SE and it might be different for others

Comment: @michaelpri - That has not been my experience, especially on the graduated sites. I know RPG for sure will deride and shout down a mod when they are obviously wrong. And, that's where a good mod team comes into play, in that other mods can discuss/override/monitor.

Comment: @JohnP Interesting, I am more active in public betas, and I have usually seen the moderators have a lot of influence. Maybe this site will be different :)

Answer (score 6):

## [Nate Barbettini](https://health.stackexchange.com/users/59/nate-barbettini)

### [Meta](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/users/59/nate-barbettini)

[http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/3851539.png?theme=dark](http://stackexchange.com/users/3851539)

I have been active on the site since day one of the private beta. I am not a health professional, but I am someone who cares a lot about having accurate, evidence-based information available online. I think that this site could become a great place for that.

I think a key duty of the early moderation team (whoever they may be) will be setting the tone of the site early on. We've already had some good meta discussion about whether alternative medicine is considered off-topic in answers, and what types of references and citations are expected, with plenty of strong opinions all around. I think that the influx of users when the site goes public will push these issues even more to the forefront. A moderation team that understands the needs of Health.SE and can help the community work through these issues will be crucial.

I would love the opportunity to take on the role of a moderator, but I will continue to be actively involved in the site regardless.

I live in the Central US timezone, so my availability can roughly be:

- Sporadic: 7 AM - 5 PM CST (1 AM - 11 AM UTC). (At work during these times)
- Active: 5 PM - 11 PM (11 AM - 5 PM UTC)

Answer (score 4):

### [Joe W](https://health.stackexchange.com/users/38/joe-w)

### [Meta](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/users/38/joe-w)

[http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1239998.png?theme=dark](http://stackexchange.com/users/1239998)

I have been visiting the site since the private beta was launched and been checking and helping deal with items in the review queues as they are added. I have been participating in the meta discussions on how the site should handle different issues. And while I don't always agree with what others are suggesting I understand one of the key duties of a moderator is to live up to the standards of the community as a whole even when they might not agree with them.

I am looking forward to watching this site grow as I think it can provide a lot of useful information as the user base grows.

I live in The United States in central  time and am generally on in the evenings in that time zone or about 11pm - 4am UTC on weekdays and on off and on from 3pm - 4am UTC on weekends.

Answer (score 1):

## [Tim](https://health.stackexchange.com/users/163/tim)

### [Meta](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/users/163/tim)

[http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/3203697.png?theme=dark](http://stackexchange.com/users/3203697/tim)

From my experience with Tim, he seems like he would make a good moderator. He is knowledgeable about Health, even though he isn't a professional and whenever I have talked to him, he has been polite and respectful.

He has also dedicated a lot of time into this site, both on beta and meta. He even [made a bunch of icons](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130/voting-for-a-new-icon) for this site based on people's ideas.

---

I accept this nomination but please see the list below.

I am Tim, I'm 16 and I live in Cambridge, UK, so will be active on the site from 3pm - 9pm UTC (Varies throughout the year due to BST)

Reasons not to elect me:

- I'm 16 years old (17 in september) and I am a full time student.
- I have 20+ exams in the next 3 months (starting 3 weeks from now) so I am going to have *no* free time.
- I will then have the summer (~2.5 months) of almost no work.
- After the summer I will be at 6th form (the 2 years before University)  and again, I will be very busy.

Comment: I saw you wonder in chat why you were receiving downvotes and I thought I'd speak up. I didn't vote for youspecifically for the reasons you listed to not elect you. I appreciate your honesty! But being honest about it doesn't make the reasons invalid. I think moderators here will need to be even more active and alert than on other SE sites, so one who has a lot of things tugging at his time, particularly while the site is still in its infancy, is probably not a wise choice.

Comment: @Sterno, that's what I expected - it would just have been nice (I feel) to have had some comments :) I was expecting to get them, but reasons always help.

Comment: I've taken-off my down-vote and actually up-voted as your posts are actually everywhere having always something to say where something isn't right which gives you the potential for a good mod.